# glib2.28 build at windows 7 32bit with mingw error. I really have no idea about it

Tags: windows, mingw, glib

I'v search for a long times to solve this error,But still have no idea.
I am building gegl at windows. when run ./configure. It said need >= glib2.28.

So I download glib. Andready to complie it.At configure It works. but a error ocurred when make.I really do not understand why have this error.I am sorry new to this.

mingw was installed by mingw-get-inst-20111118.exe

[image: this is error]

could anyone can help me solve this error.
help please!

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v  done with this error.

lib tool need libz.dll.a file,but I only have libz.a .I install libz.dll.a in lib path. and it works.